# How to disable the calender popup from bootstrap date picker using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to disable the calender popup from bootstrap date picker using jquery??

`$("#id").val('').attr('disabled',true).trigger("liszt:updated");`

is not working also .prop is not working..

Comment: Dis `$('#datepicker').datepicker({ enableOnReadonly: false });` not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options for this in the official documentation.
At: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html

Try this:

```
$("#id").datepicker({ enableOnReadonly: false });
```

*(where `#id` is the selector for your date picker, and the `enableOnReadonly: false` key value pair has just been added into the `datepicker` options JSON object in the param)*

Comment: Hmm, any chance you could post a bit more of your code, then I can try it out?

Comment: I want to disable the bootstrap datepicker on selecting a dropdown..i have added those condtions.All is working fine..Except i am unable to disable the date picker.$("#id").val('').attr('disabled',true).trigger("liszt:updated");